# C - Extract substring

Tags: c

How can I extract "bon" and "jour" in a string like this: 
\0\0bon\0\0jour\0 to an array of string like: [0] = bon | [1] = jour | [2] = NULL (end of tab) 
And here is my (try)code:

```
char    **ft_split(char const *s, char c)
{
    char    *s1;
    char    *tmp;
    char    **res;
    int     i;
    size_t  len = 100 /* how can I guess the size ? */;

    s1 = strdup(s);
    res = malloc(len + 1);
    if (!res)
        return (res);
    i = 0;
    while (*s1)
    {
        tmp = strchr(s1, c) + 1;
        if (!tmp)
            break ;
        if (*tmp)
            res[i++] = strdup(tmp);
        s1 = tmp + 1;
    }
    res[i] = 0;
    return (res); 
}

int     main(void)
{
    char    **res = ft_split("\0bon\0jour", '\0');

    int i = 0;
    while (res[i])
        printf("%s\n", res[i++]);
    
    i = 0;
    while (res[i])
        free(res[i++]);
    free(res);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You've tried to solve this problem. What output do you see from trying your code?

Comment: Thanks for reply, and I get an empty output

Comment: I hope you realize `'\0'` is the null terminator in a C string. A string where the first character is a null terminator is an _empty_ string. Or does your string contain `'\'` and `'0'` characters?

Comment: Your description says `\0\0bon\0\0jour\0`; why is your test case `\0bon\0jour\0`?

Comment: Your function does not use the `c` parameter anywhere; your test case passes a `/` for it. What is the intent?

Comment: This is not what the common `ft_split` exercise specifies the `ft_split` routine is supposed to do. Are you sure you have understood the assignment correctly?

Comment: Which is correct - the question or the code sample? Your questions asks about strings preceded by 2x null characters, yet your code shows 1x null characters between them. Kaz already asked about exactly this.

Comment: Embedded `'\0'` 1x or 2x or 'n' times is irrelevant... There is no way to distinguish the embedded from the terminating one the compiler will affix. And, any attempt to find a 2nd (or n'th) '\0' beyond the one the compiler supplied is going beyond the boundary of the array... In short, the **size** of the original "null terminated array of characters" **must** be known to the function...

Comment: @Fe2O3: Multiple non-empty strings can be encoded in an array by using a empty string as the meta-terminator: `abc\0def\0\0`. OP has likely confused something about the assignment they were given.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That is not what the OP asks about... Commas are used as field separators in CSV files with LF as used as meta-terminators... Since the OP did not mention any "meta-terminator" (and even provided two differing "sting" prototypes), I stand by my answer below.

Comment: @Fe2O3: I know it is not what they asked about. As I wrote, OP has likely confused something about the assignment they were given. We have seen `ft_split` assignments before on Stack Overflow, and students often present misunderstandings of various sorts.

Comment: @EricPostpischil My answer below clearly states that the OP examples provided are not amenable to processing (without a meta-terminator or some other assumptions). That answer also changes the function parameters that the OP provided in order to yield a working implementation of what I _presumed_ to be the task. One must always be careful about presuming, I suppose... There are many ways to 'correct' this OP for it to make sense. I chose one...

Comment: @Fe2O3: Nobody is criticizing you or your answer. I am giving you information that comes from years of experience with student exercises and questions. It is information that is useful to avoid leading the student down a rabbit hole based on their mistake. No teacher gave them an exercise to parse a string like `"\0\0bon\0\0jour\0" without further information like how many strings are in it or where the last string ends or something like that. OP has made some mistake in stating the problem. Now you have that information. Do not take people giving you information as an affront.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This OP may represent a 2nd pass of a "filter" whose effect is much like the utility "strings". (1st pass sets all no-printable bytes to 0; 2nd pass extracts remaining 'n' strings from that.) Who are we to presume we know the full context of the question? "Information" is more reliable that "speculation"... My answer below gives the results the OP explicitly wrote were wanted, regardless of context. You choose to know the question better than the OP who wrote the OP... com si com sa, I suppose....

Comment: @Fe2O3: Re “Who are we to presume we know the full context of the question?”: It is not a presumption; the name is information. `ft_split` is not a random name. It is the name used in a known exercise. As I wrote, we have seen this before.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Waiting for this question to be closed as a "duplicate"...

Comment: @Fe2O3: I did not say the question is a duplicate. The fact it uses a routine that is used in other questions does not mean it is asking the same question about that routine as other questions. And now you are just arguing. Once again, nobody said your answer was wrong or you were wrong about needing the length of a string in certain situations. I was just sharing information with you. So think about what you are doing. If other people have information that might be useful, do you want them to share it with you or not?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sharing is why we all are here! `:-)`

Comment: Are you sure the representation isn't supposed to be this one:  `foo\0bar\0baz\0\0`? Microsoft uses something like this for a list-of-strings value in the Registry: the individual strings in the list are null, terminated, and an extra null terminates the list. This means that it cannot contain an empty string: the double null terminator looks exactly like an extra empty string tacked onto the list; the list is "empty-string terminated", where the terminating empty string is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing embedded NUL characters, your function MUST receive the size of the array of characters that it is expected to deal with. Otherwise, there is no difference between the literal '\0' that are embedded and the compiler-supplied '\0' at the end of the "literal string".

In the code of the function you ask, `/* how can I guess the size ? */`. You cannot.

However, this seems to work nicely using the string from your question...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **ft_split( char const *s, int sz ) {
    char **res = NULL;
    int n = 0;

    for( const char *p = s; p-s < sz; p++ )
        if( *p ) {
            res = (char**)realloc( res, (n+1) * sizeof *res );
            if( res == NULL ) {
                fprintf( stderr, "realloc failed\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }
            res[ n++ ] = strdup( p );
            p += strlen( p ) - 1;
        }
    res = (char **)realloc( res, (n+1) * sizeof *res );
    // omitting validation of realloc success for brevity
    res[ n ] = NULL;
    return res;
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "\0\0bon\0\0jour\0";
    char **res = ft_split( str, sizeof str );

    int i;
    for( i = 0; res[i]; i++ ) {
        printf( "%d - %s\n", i, res[i]);
        free(res[i]);
    }
    printf( "%d - %p\n", i, res[i]);
    // free(res[i]); // this is a NULL pointer

    free(res);

    return (0);
}
```

Output

```
0 - bon
1 - jour
2 - 00000000
```

Finally, the word "bonjour" is spelled correctly as a single word. "bon" "jour" are two separate words, so the question's sample "words" are somewhat misleading.

EDIT: The sequel (with a smattering of `const`) that does not make copies of segments but, instead, sets pointers into the original string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char **ft_split( char const *s, int sz ) {
    const char **res = NULL;
    int n = 0;

    for( const char *p = s; p-s < sz; p++ )
        if( *p ) {
            res = (const char**)realloc( res, (n+1) * sizeof *res );
            if( res == NULL ) {
                fprintf( stderr, "realloc failed\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }
            res[ n++ ] = p; // point into original string segment
            p += strlen( p ) - 1;
        }
    res = (const char **)realloc( res, (n+1) * sizeof *res );
    // still omitting validation of realloc success for brevity
    res[ n ] = NULL;
    return res;
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "\0\0bon\0\0jour\0";
    const char **res = ft_split( str, sizeof str );

    int i = 0;
    do {
        printf( "%d - %s\n", i, res[i] ? res[i] : "NULL" );
    } while( res[i++] );

    free(res);

    return (0);
}
```

Output

```
0 - bon
1 - jour
2 - NULL
```

EDIT2:

To cover all the bases (code and comments received), some additional development is demonstrated below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Two "helper functions" to test the ASCII value of a character
bool cmp00( char c ) { return c != 0x00; }
bool cmp2F( char c ) { return c != 0x2F; }

// "do or die" allocation (with growth) and initialisation
const char **safeAlloc( const char **p, const int n, const size_t size ) {
    if( ( p = (const char**)realloc( p, (n+1) * size ) ) == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "realloc failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    p[n] = NULL;
    return p;
}

// Hardly recognisable function signature
const char **ft_split( char *s, int sz, bool(*cmp)( char ) ) {
    int n = 0;
    const char **res = safeAlloc( NULL, n, sizeof *res );

    // examine bytes of array
    for( char *p = s; p-s < sz; p++ )
        if( cmp( *p ) ) { // first byte that is not separator??
            res = (const char**)safeAlloc( res, ++n, sizeof *res );
            res[ n-1 ] = p++; // point into original array segment
            while( p-s < sz && cmp(*p) ) p++; // change non-null separators to '\0'
            *p = '\0';
        }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    char ex1[] = "\0\0bon\0\0jour\0"; // to use sizeof instead of strlen()
    char ex2[] = "\0bon\0jour";

    typedef struct {
        char *txt;
        bool (*cmp)( char );
        int sz;
    } tests_t;

    // 4 test cases derived from OP 'clues'
    tests_t str[] = {
        { ex1, cmp00, sizeof ex1 },
        { ex2, cmp00, sizeof ex2 },
        { "//bon//jour/", cmp2F, }, // strlen() performed below
        { "/bon/jour", cmp2F },
    };
    const int nStr = sizeof str/sizeof str[0];

    for( int i = 0; i < nStr; i++ ) {
        tests_t *pt = &str[i];

        if( pt->sz == 0 ) pt->sz = strlen( pt->txt );

        // make 'mutable' copy of array
        char wrkbuf[45];
        memcpy( wrkbuf, pt->txt, pt->sz );
        pt->txt = wrkbuf;

        // invocation
        const char **res = ft_split( pt->txt, pt->sz, pt->cmp );

        // confirmation
        int ii = 0;
        do {
            printf( "res[%d] - %s\n", ii, res[ii] ? res[ii] : "NULL" );
        } while( res[ii++] );

        free(res);
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0; // return is NOT a function call. "()" unnecessary
}
```

Output

```
res[0] - bon
res[1] - jour
res[2] - NULL

res[0] - bon
res[1] - jour
res[2] - NULL

res[0] - bon
res[1] - jour
res[2] - NULL

res[0] - bon
res[1] - jour
res[2] - NULL
```